# Android Facebook SDK - How To Query Facebook Notifications

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, notifications

I have the Facebook SDK for Android working in my app. I can't seem to find any examples or documentation on how to use the SDK code to get Notifications. I have the permission "manage_notifications" set and I am assuming that I need to use the .request() method, but the graphPath parameter eludes me.

Does anyone have an example of how to get the Facebook notifications using the Facebook SDK for Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answers are helpfull, what I was looking for was an example of the Android Code. I have figured it out though and have posted it here. The code below gets the logged in/authenticated users notifications.

```
//Initialze your Facebook object, etc.
Facebook _facebook = ...
...
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, _accessToken);
String result = _facebook.request("me/notifications", bundle, "GET");
```

Then you will need to parse the string "result". It's in json format. Here is an example of what that will look like:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResults = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonNotificationDataArray = jsonObjectResults.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i=0;i<jsonNotificationDataArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonNotificationData = jsonNotificationDataArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (_debug) Log.v("Title: " + jsonNotificationData.getString("title"));
}
```

I hope that other people find this useful.

Comment: Where do i add this code.. Within the onCreate() or onComplete()

Comment: @Vivekanand This code should be added wherever you want to query the Facebook notification json data. It can be anywhere.

Comment: _facebook object is depreciated :)

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani - Yes it is. Do you know how to accomplish to query this data using the Facebook SDK v3.0?

Comment: You can Use <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton/> widget from Facebook SDK 3.0 Library and add this widget to your Layout.xml file.
This Widget Manages Facebook Sessions itself, so you don't have to worry about that. After adding this widget just simply add permissions to this widget:
`
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_stream", "email", "read_friendlists", "publish_stream"));`

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check the answer below.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add manage_notification permission.Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

By default the /USER_ID/notifications endpoint only includes unread notifications (i.e there'll only be a return value if the third jewel on the top line of Facebook.com is lit up and has a red number inside it)

If you want to also include notifications the user has already read, you can make a request to `/USER_ID/notifications?include_read=1` - manage_notifications is the correct extended permission for this

Comment: This information is very helpful, thank you. I was however looking for Android specific code regarding the request() method.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add manage_notification permission.Thankyou.i tried using this : facebook.authorize(this,
     new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" , "manage_notifications" }... but it doesnot work.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Session Object of Facebook SDK 3.0 to ensure the Session is opened.
After that you can get the JSON data with the help of following code:

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) 
    {
        //access_token = session.getAccessToken();
        Request graphRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/home", new    
        Request.Callback() 
    {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) 
            {
                //Create the GraphObject from the response
                GraphObject responseGraphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                //Create the JSON object
                JSONObject json = responseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
                try 
                {
                    YOUR_JSON_ARRAY= json.getJSONArray("data");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(graphRequest); 
     }
```

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for. Let me try thing out when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a FQL query. The format of the query will be

```
SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href
FROM notification
WHERE recipient_id=userid
AND is_unread = 1
AND is_hidden = 0
```

Please refer to this page for details http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/

The results of this query can be received in onComplete() of a listener which implements BaseRequestListener.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get notifications

```
final Session session =Session.getActiveSession();
            if(session.isOpened()){  
                String aaa=new String();
                aaa="SELECT title_text,updated_time FROM notification WHERE recipient_id=me() AND is_unread=1";
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("q", aaa);
                     new Request(session,"/fql",params,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {
                                 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                     try
                                     {
                                        GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
                                        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
                                        JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );
                                        String splitting=arr.toString().replaceAll("\\\\|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]", "");
                                        String[] arrayresponse=splitting.split("\\,");
                                        String s = "";
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayresponse.length; i++) {
                                            if (arrayresponse[i].length()>13){
                                                if (arrayresponse[i].substring(1,13).equals("updated_time"))
                                                    s+="* "+getDate(Long.valueOf(arrayresponse[i].substring(15,arrayresponse[i].length())))+"\n";
                                                else
                                                    s+="   "+arrayresponse[i].substring(14,arrayresponse[i].length()-1)+"\n\n";

                                            }
                                        }
                                        text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        NotificationMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        NotificationMessage.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                                        NotificationMessage.setText(s);
                                        readMailBox(session);

                                     }catch ( Throwable t )
                                     {
                                         t.printStackTrace();
                                     }


                                 }
                             }  
                     ).executeAsync();
            }
             else{
    //           NotificationMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
             }
     }
```