# Need facebook as social network engine in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a mobile app where I will need a sort of small social network where people can discuss things and also can post comments and likes on posts.
I am willing to use facebook as a back end social engine so that I would be able to handle multiple peoples' interaction (likes, posts, comments) and also for better security. I am stuck here as mobiles sdks and graph api would be very complex to achieve this. Is there any sort of sdk, framework available which integrates facebook as social network engine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there a facebook sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ .Atleast do some research or just google it , before posting here !!!

Comment: @RachitaNanda I have already used it. I need suggestion, using this sdk to get/post every update on mobile app or to use any existing fine framework that will do the job for me.

Comment: one more thing, I want latest update on facebook(comments,like on my post) on my application. Is there any way to use push notification of facebook in my application.

Comment: check my answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use facebook sdk for this purpose.

- Check this to get started there a facebook sdk
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
- To get facebook notifications refer to [Android Facebook SDK - How To Query Facebook Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342876/android-facebook-sdk-how-to-query-facebook-notifications)

Hope this helps!